# How to find the first empty cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My sheet look like : 
[image]

I have a function to get index of the **LAST** empty cell in column A:

```
NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

This function works to write on second array (Type2).

But now, i would like a function to get index of the **FIRST** empty cell in column A. So i went to this website: [Select first empty cell](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/find-select-first-blank-cell-column-vba/) and i tried to adapt code but it's doesn't work:

```
If Array= "Type1" Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
       If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then NextRow = cell: Exit For 'ERROR 1004
    Next cell
End If
If Array= "Type2" Then 'It s works
    NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextRow) = "TEST"
```

Could you help me to adapt my code to have `NextRow = IndexOf FIRST empty cell in A` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use the same method you did to get the last one.

```
NextRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

Comment: `xlDown` is possibly misleading as it finds the the last cell in an area - so if A2 was blank but A3 was used, it won't get to A3. Conversely if range is empty it will jump to the last row on the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I do this and it' works:

```
If Array= "Type1" Then
       Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
               If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                    NextRow = cell.Row
                    Exit For
                    MsgBox NextRow
                End If
            Next cell
    End If
    If Array= "Type2" Then 'It s works
        NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextRow) = "TEST"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look bottom up for this.

And `Find` is better than `xlUp`.

```
Sub FindBlank()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Last used cell is " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox ws.Name & " row1 is completely empty", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach to some of the answers, but with the goal of repeatedly looking down the column until I could guarantee that there was no more populated cells below.

I turned this into a small function that I put in a standard module:-

```
Public Function getFirstBlankRowNumberOnSheet(sht As Worksheet, Optional startingRef As String = "A1") As Long 'may get more than 32767 rows in a spreadsheet (but probably not!)
  Dim celTop As Range
  Dim celBottom As Range
  On Error Resume Next
  Set celTop = sht.Range(startingRef)

  Do
    Set celBottom = celTop.End(xlDown)
    Set celTop = celBottom.Offset(1) 'This will throw an error when the bottom cell is on the last available row (1048576)
  Loop Until IsEmpty(celBottom.value)

  getFirstBlankRowNumberOnSheet = celTop.Row

End Function
```

*This will throw an error if there happens to be content in the row #1048576! The particulars of this are dependent on the Excel version I suppose in terms of maximum row cont allowed.*